# ASP.Net MVC 3, how to redirect almost all page to one action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

For an application, I've users which have a profile. This application is only "with invitation", and I need that the user fills its profile before doing anything else.

I've a "IsCompleted" boolean attribute on its profile, so I've no problem to know if the user has to finish its inscription or not.

But how can I create something which check, on all page that the user has to be authenticated, that the user must be completed?

I thought to create an custom AuthorizeAttribute(in fact I've already one custom, which check some roles), but I don't know if it's the right place to make this kind of controls, and how can I distinct in the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` if the request has been rejected because the login wasn't valid or because the user didn't fullfilled it's informations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

a)  Put them into a 'limited' role until they enter their profile, and let the base authorisation code handle it, then add them to a 'full' role on entry of details.

b)  Override the OnActionExecuting method in your controllers (or better on base controller that you use), to check to see if the user has entered their profile, before processing the rest of the action.

Comment: for your A). I thought about that, but how to manage that when I've an incomplete profile, I'm redirected to my profile page, otherwise to the login page?
B)Can this be done through filter?

Comment: On your login action, and they are of the appropriate role, you redirect to the profile page.  If they try and access anything else, they go back to login, their own fault for trying to bypass your system.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* I understood what you mean then you have that, simply use the standard authentication method. Do not forget you can use groups and roles so even if a user is authenticated it can be excluded from some pages.

Comment: Same response than Paddy:"how to manage that when I've an incomplete profile, I'm redirected to my profile page, otherwise to the login page?"

Comment: From MSDN: the framework returns HTTP 401 error status (default redirect to login page in roles provider is enabled). You can use that with a custom page for errors (to redirect where appropriate) or override OnAuthorize() in a base class for your controllers (check whatever you have to check and redirect to profile page is unsatisfied).